# как сложить два текстовых файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Есть класс  с параметром path, который есть путь до текстового файла:

```
class Text():
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path
```

Далее мы создаем три объекта и мне необходимо сложить содежимое файлов двух объектов в файл третьего:

```
a = Text("file1")
b = Text("file2")
c = Text("file3")
c = a + b
```

Я понимаю что задачка простая, может есть какие либо стандартные решения, но я только начал знакомиться с python. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В чём вопрос? Как перегрузку оператора (такого как +) в Питоне реализовать? Или вы не знаете как скопировать из одного файла в другой? (Такие вопросы по отдельности лучше задавать, чтобы ответы кому-нибудь кроме вас могли пригодиться)

Comment: В общем да, стыдно но честно признаюсь что как это делается в python не знаю. И думаю есть какие нибудь стандарные решения или готовые билиотеки для этого.

Comment: дело не в том что вы знаете, а насколько полезен вопрос для будущих посетителей из гугла. По отдельности вопросы более полезны чем вместе: 1- cat утилита до сих пор используется, поэтому полезно знать как её в Питоне можно реализовать  2- перегрузка операторов в Питоне также часто используется и никто из нас не рождается с этим знанием жёстко прописанном в мозгах. Желательно одной проблемой на вопрос ограничиться (даже если людей оба вопроса интересуют, может быть проще по отдельности с ними разобраться. Если необходимо, зная ответы на индивидуальные вопросы, можно спросить как объединить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Было интересно вспомнить учебные задания, которые сами по себе дурацкие, но позволяли узнавать новое:

```
class Text:
    def __init__(self, file_name='default.txt', content=''):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.content = content

        self.save()

    def get_content(self):
        with open(self.file_name, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            return f.read()

    def save(self):
        with open(self.file_name, mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(self.content)

    def __add__(self, other):
        new_text = Text(
            file_name=self.file_name + '_' + other.file_name,
            content=self.get_content() + other.get_content()
        )
        return new_text


a = Text("file1", content='Hello ')
b = Text("file2", content='World!')
c = a + b
print(c.file_name)  # file1_file2
print(c.content)  # Hello World!

c.file_name = 'file3'
c.save()

print(open(c.file_name).read())  # Hello World!
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Имеено то что я хотел.

Answer (score 0):

Если файлы маленькие:

```
from pathlib import Path

Path("file3").write_text(Path("file1").read_text() + 
                         Path("file2").read_text())
```

Если файлы побольше, то можно построчно копировать:

```
from fileinput import FileInput

with FileInput(["file1", "file2"]) as input_lines:
    with open("file3", "w") as output_file:
        output_file.writelines(input_lines)
```

Эти варианты поддерживают универсальный режим строк и позволяют использовать разные кодировки для файлов.

Если нормализация окончания строк не нужна и все файлы в одной кодировке, то можно в виде байт копировать как `cat` утилита:

```
from shutil import copyfileobj 

with open("file3", "wb") as output_file:
    for filename in ["file1", "file2"]:
        with open(filename, "rb") as input_file:
            copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)
```

При наличии ошибок, разные варианты по-разному себя ведут.

В зависимости от системы, можно более эффективные методы найти. К примеру, [`os.sendfile()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14411471/4279).

Comment: Отличный ответ. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Возможность "суммирования" объектов делается через добавление к классу метода: `def __add__(self, other)` в котором вам нужно будет реализовать соответствующую логику.

Comment: Спасибо, но вопрос как раз в этой логике.

Comment: @Eriixon И в чем проблема? Открыли файл, прочитали, закрыли. При "сложении" добавили к полученным данным считанные данные из второго файла.

Comment: Я был бы благодарен если бы вы подсказали как это реализовать.